# How to use an array to use Paperclip's photo.url method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

**The App**:
My application has many buses. Each bus has many photos of the interior and exterior. *Some* of the interior photos have an associated image that indicates the location on the bus where the photos were taken (like a "You are Here" marker on a map), which is assigned through `:parent_id` attribute that corresponds to the "parent" photos id.

**The Goal:**
Output the URL for the "child" image if a selected photo is a "parent," and keep blank if not.

**The Problem:**
The only way I know how to find any particular associated image brings back an array. Unfortunately for me, the `photo.url` method that comes with Paperclip can't work with an array.

This is closest to what I want, but, again, it brings back an array that I can't use to find the image URL.

```
def assigned_floorplan(where I pass in all the parent images as a params)
  bus_images.all(conditions: { is_floorplan: true, parent_id: params.id })
end
```

Is this a dead end, or is there a way to pull out the id of the associated image from the array so that I can use the `photo.url` method? Or am I going about this the wrong way? I'm willing to approach this problem totally differently if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `photo.url` method for each image separately. A nested loop would work:

```
<% @parent_images.each do |parent_image| %>

  <%= parent_image.photo.url %>

  <% parent_image.child_images.each do |child_image| %>
    <%= child_image.photo.url %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```